# Dynamically returning serialized RestSharp results

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

Trying to make a generic method to call REST endpoints using RestSharp the only issue I'm having is returning the content as **dynamic**.

Response.Data is null and Response.Content is always a string. I would like the return value to be at least an anonymous type.

```
public T Call<T>(string url, Method method = Method.GET, ResponseType type = ResponseType.JSON, params Parameter[] parameters)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(url, method);

    switch (type)
    {
        case ResponseType.JSON:
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            break;
        case ResponseType.XML:
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
            break;
    }

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        request.AddParameter(parameter);

    var response = _client.Execute<dynamic>(request);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ErrorMessage) || response.ErrorException != null)
        throw new System.Exception(response.ErrorMessage, response.ErrorException);

    return response.Data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the type T, can you not do:

```
var response = _client.Execute<T>(request);
```

Comment: Won't dynamic create an anonymous type as where Object will not?

Comment: this should work, but remember to add where T : new() to the end of the method signature.